# Messages are not sent to Kafka from PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I want to send data to Kafka using Python Kafka connector. Everything works fine when I run the code from `pyspark` shell.
However, when I run it as `spark-submit`, the messgaes are not sent. There are no errors in the logs and the program execution appears as succeeded. But the messages are not sent to Kafka.

```
import json
import datettime
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:9092')
end = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
country = "es"
message = {'country': country, 'end': end, 'status': '1'}
msg = json.dumps(message)
print(msg)
producer.send('testtopic', msg)
```

I do not understand why it happens. Below I provide parameters of `spark-submit`:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 11g \
--driver-cores 3 \
--num-executors 6 \
--executor-memory 6g \
--executor-cores 2 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=1500 \
--queue t1 \
s3://my-test-bucket/test1/test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `producer.flush()` after `producer.send('testtopic', msg)`. Only in this case, messages are sent to the Kafka queue, when I run the code with `spark-submit`.
Otherwise, the messages are not sent.

However, it's curious that `producer.flush()` is not needed when the code is executed from pyspark shell.

Answer (score 0):

The producer polls for a batch of messages from the batch queue, one batch per partition. A batch is ready when one of the following is true:

batch.size is reached. Note: Larger batches typically have better compression ratios and higher throughput, but they have higher latency.

linger.ms (time-based batching threshold) is reached. Note: There is no simple guideilne for setting linger.ms values; you should test settings on specific use cases. For small events (100 bytes or less), this setting does not appear to have much impact.

Another batch to the same broker is ready.

The producer calls flush() or close().